# RxJava flatmap chaining requests

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, chaining, flatmap

i am using Retrofit with RxJAva for an app that gets Rss Feeds, but the rss doesn't contain all the informations so i use jsoup to parse every item link, to retrieve the image and the article's description. now i am using it this way:

```
public Observable<Rss> getDumpData() {
    return newsAppService.getDumpData()
            .flatMap(rss -> Observable.from(rss.channel.items)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(Checked.f1(item -> Observable.just(Jsoup.connect(item.link).get())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(document -> document.select("div[itemprop=image] > img").first())
                    .doOnNext(element -> item.image = element.attr("src"))
            )))
            .defaultIfEmpty(rss)
            .ignoreElements()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

and i am getting an error on this line: `defaultIfEmpty(rss)`
it doesn't recognize rss of the flatmap. and when i move the  `defaultIfEmpty(rss)` in flatmap brackets i have another error saying that the return type must be changed to Element. is their any solution ?

Comment: What are trying to achieve by passing `flatMap` parameter to `defaultIfEmpty` parameter? You want to catch an Exception?

Comment: @R.Zagórski its just in case of an error its emit the source Observable

Comment: Do you expect error to happen from `newsAppService.getDumpData()` or from your transformation to get image?

Comment: yes @R.Zagórski i expect it from the transformation it can throw an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you need to get rid of all the concurrency with observeOn and use subscribeOn.

```
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Please consider using observeOn with AndroidScheduler if want to sync back data from another thread back to the event-loop. Normally you would use observeOn before subscribing to a observable in order to sync back to ui-loop and change ui-information.

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Secondly it is not recommended to mutate objects in the pipeline. You should return a new object very time.

```
.doOnNext(element -> item.image = element.attr("src"))
```

I tried to refactor your solution under consideration of the first two points. I am using RxJava2-RC5

The flatMap operator has many overloades. One of them provides a function to zip together the incoming value and the created value.

```
Observable<Rss> rssItemObservable = newsService.getDumpData()
                .flatMap(rss -> getRssItemInformation(rss).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                        (r, rItemList) -> {
                            Rss rInterim = new Rss();
                            rInterim.items = rItemList;
                            return rInterim;
                        });
```

Helping-method for retrieving information for each item in Rss. Please consider using the overload with maxConcurrency, because on default it will subscribe to every stream at once. Therefore flatMap would create many http-requests.

```
private Observable<List<RssItem>> getRssItemInformation(Rss rss) {
        return Observable.fromIterable(rss.items)
                .flatMap(rssItem -> getImageUrl(rssItem).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), (rItem, img) -> {
                    RssItem item = new RssItem();
                    printCurrentThread("merge1");
                    item.image = img;
                    item.link = rItem.link;
                    return item;
                }).toList().toObservable();
}
```

Helping-method for retrieving the image url. Returning observable is not opinionated about concurrency. If an error occurs, an empty string will be returned as default value.

```
private Observable<String> getImageUrl(String link) {
           return Observable.fromCallable(() -> Jsoup.connect(link).get())
                .map(document -> document.select("div[itemprop=image] > img").first())
                .map(element -> element.attr("src"))
                .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                    return Observable.just("");
                });
}
```

You may look at the full example at github.gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a8e36205fc2430517c66c802f6eef38e

Comment: Hans just wanted to say thanks, this answer has indirectly helped me to solve my issue in chaining request. I was not calling subscribeOn(Schedulers.io() in chaining request, I mean while making another API calls in flatMap.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix internal parameter of one `RxJava` parameter (`flatMap` lambda parameter) with another operator parameter (`defaultIfEmpty`).

First of all, create a helper function to keep main reactive stream cleaner:

```
private Observable<List<Item>> getDetails(List<Item> items) {
    return Observable.from(items)
               .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .flatMap(Checked.f1(item ->
                   Observable.zip(
                       Observable.just(item),
                            Observable.just(Jsoup.connect(item.link).get())
                           .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                           .map(document -> document.select("div[itemprop=image] > img").first()),
                           (itemInner, element) -> {
                                itemInner.image = element.attr("src");
                                return itemInner;
                           }
                   )
               ))
               .toList();
}
```

Then reformat main function:

```
newsAppService.getDumpData()
    .flatMap(rss ->
        Observable.zip(
            Observable.<Rss>just(rss),
            getDetails(rss.channel.items),
            (rssInner, items) -> {
                rssInner.channel.items = items;
                return rss;
            }).onErrorResumeNext((throwable -> Observable.just(rss))
        )
    )
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Hope I got your aim properly. It may not work, as I am unable to test it, however I hope you get the idea. The reason I used `.zip` functions it that you can't loose the reference to the currently parsed `item` or `rss`

Comment: thanks a lot @R.Zagórski it works perfectly, but i dont understand very well the code, i will read the zip documentation, you saved me