# How send a chain POST request RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I need to send the first `POST` request to the server, insert the received response into the second `POST` request and send it back to the server. How can I implement this with `RxJava`? At the moment, everything works, but the second question does not have time to get an answer from the first request and the `imageMediaId` field is sent empty.

My function:

```
fun uploadNewImageAndContact(toPath: String?, newContactApi: ContactsApi) {
        val file = File(toPath)
        val fileReqBody: RequestBody = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val part: MultipartBody.Part =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.name, fileReqBody)

        // First Request
        imagesService.postImage(part).enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                if (response.code() == 201) {
                    // Get Image response Id
                    val gson = Gson()
                    val imageResponse =
                        gson.fromJson(response.body()?.string(), ImageResponse::class.java)
                    imageMediaId = imageResponse.ids[0]

                    // Second Request
                    contactsService.postNewContact(newContactApi)
                        .enqueue(object : Callback<ContactsApi> {
                            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ContactsApi>, t: Throwable) {

                            }

                            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ContactsApi>, response: Response<ContactsApi>) {

                            }

                        })
                }
            }

        })

    }
```

My ViewModel function:

```
val newContactsApi = ContactsApi(id = "", firstName = mFirstName, lastName = mLastName, phone = mPhone,
                email = mEmail, notes = mNotes, images = "https://mydb.site.io/media/${apiRepository.imageMediaId}")


            apiRepository.uploadNewImageAndContact(toPath, newContactsApi)
```

Comment: Use RxJava FlatMap method.
Here is an example of how to use it to chain 2 responses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132703/rxjava-flatmap-chaining-requests

Comment: I need a solution on Kotlin but I can't find anything

Comment: Would suggest you look into Retrofit and RXRetrofit, will make this far easier for you. But, as GuessWho said, flatMap is the operator you'll want to use to chain 2 Observable REST requests together.